# Parse JSON data from file upload

Tags: php, json, laravel, laravel-5

I have an input that select json file

In my controller, I did

```
dd(Input::all());
```

I got

[image]

My goal is to parse the JSON file that I got and loop through them.

I've tried

```
$string = file_get_contents(Input::get('fileinput'));
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: What does `Input::get('fileinput')` return?

Comment: I'm not sure why it return `null` .

Comment: i have updated my answer, it should work now !

Answer (score 2):

`Input::get` is used to retrieve an input item from the request ( $_REQUEST ),
you should use `Input::file` instead, which is used to retrieve a file from the request, and returns a `Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile` instance.

example :

```
<?php
$file = Input::file('fileinput');
if($file === null) {
    throw new Exception('File was not sent !');
}
if($file->isReadable()) {
    $file->open('r');
    $contents = $file->fread($file->getSize());
    $json = json_decode($contents, true);
} else {
    throw new Exception('File is not readable');
}
```

[`Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Http/UploadedFile.php) extends [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php) extends [`Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\File`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/File.php) extends [`SplFileInfo`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/splfileinfo.construct.php)

Comment: I an trying it now.

Comment: I did that I kept getting `null`

Comment: what returns null exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Laravel version 6 and the other solutions did not work. Following worked for me:

```
$file = request()->fileinput;      // <input type="file" name="fileinput" />
$content = file_get_contents($file);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

Answer (score -1):

I did this and it works for me

```
Input::file('fileinput')->move(public_path(), 'fortinet_logs.json');
$string = file_get_contents(public_path().'/fortinet_logs.json');
$json = json_decode($string, true);
```